# How can I prevent inserting duplicate data into a SQL Server table where value is multiple

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, insert-update

I have a declared some of data that need to be inserted into SQL, what should I do to check the data in SQL to prevent same data inserted into table?

123(AA) is already uploaded and 123(BB) is a new invitee.
At this case, server should upload just 123(BB).

```
 declare @inviteename VARCHAR(500) = 'aa,bb' ,@inviteephoneno VARCHAR(500) = '123,45',@Code varchar(10)='123', @CustomerID VARCHAR(50) = 10  

   DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
inviteename VARCHAR(100), 
inviteephoneno VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO @tbl ( inviteename, inviteephoneno) select  @inviteename, @inviteephoneno;

   DECLARE @temp TABLE (
inviteename VARCHAR(100), 
inviteephoneno VARCHAR(100),
CustomerID VARCHAR(100)
);

;WITH cte1 AS
(
    SELECT  value AS inviteename , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS seq
    FROM @tbl CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(inviteename, ',')
), cte2 AS
(
    SELECT  value AS inviteephoneno , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS seq
    FROM @tbl CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(inviteephoneno, ',')
)

INSERT INTO @temp ( inviteename, inviteephoneno,CustomerID)
SELECT cte1.inviteename, cte2.inviteephoneno,@CustomerID   FROM cte1 INNER JOIN cte2 ON cte2.seq = cte1.seq; 

if not  exists (select 1 from test a where a.inviteename= (select InviteeName from @temp a where a.CustomerID=@CustomerID)
 and a.InviteeMobileNumber = (select InviteeMobileNumber from @temp a where a.CustomerID=@CustomerID))    
  begin
  INSERT dbo.test (InviteeName ,InviteeMobileNumber ) 
   SELECT a.inviteename, a.inviteephoneno  FROM @temp a 

  end
```

test table

```
create table test ( 
id int identity(1,1)
, inviteename VARCHAR(100)
, inviteephoneno VARCHAR(100) );
```

Comment: If you want to stop duplicate values, then use a `UNIQUE INDEX` or `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`, however, the values `'123(AA)'` and `'123(BB)'` *are* different/unique, so I don't understand the problem here.

Comment: can you provide a create table for your dbo.test table

Comment: Instead of INSERT you should try using MERGE statement instead.  It already takes care of identifying duplicates and provides separate execution paths for the two cases (duplicate and non-duplicate).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/bb522522(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

> ```
>     create table test ( 
>     id int identity(1,1)
>     , inviteename VARCHAR(100)
>     , InviteeMobileNumber VARCHAR(100) );
> GO
> ```

> ```
>      declare @inviteename VARCHAR(500) = 'aa,bb' 
>      ,@inviteephoneno VARCHAR(500) = '123
>      ,45',@Code varchar(10)='123'
>      , @CustomerID VARCHAR(50) = 10  
>     
>        DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
>     inviteename VARCHAR(100), 
>     inviteephoneno VARCHAR(100)
>     );
>     
>     INSERT INTO @tbl ( inviteename, inviteephoneno) select  @inviteename, @inviteephoneno;
>     
>        DECLARE @temp TABLE (
>     inviteename VARCHAR(100), 
>     inviteephoneno VARCHAR(100),
>     CustomerID VARCHAR(100)
>     );
>     
>     ;WITH cte1 AS
>     (
>         SELECT  value AS inviteename , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS seq
>         FROM @tbl CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(inviteename, ',')
>     ), cte2 AS
>     (
>         SELECT  value AS inviteephoneno , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS seq
>         FROM @tbl CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(inviteephoneno, ',')
>     )
>     
>     INSERT INTO @temp ( inviteename, inviteephoneno,CustomerID)
>     SELECT cte1.inviteename, cte2.inviteephoneno,@CustomerID   FROM cte1 INNER JOIN cte2 ON cte2.seq = cte1.seq; 
>     MERGE dbo.test AS T
> USING @temp AS S
> ON (T.inviteename = S.inviteename AND T.InviteeMobileNumber = S.inviteephoneno) 
> WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET  
>     THEN INSERT (InviteeName ,InviteeMobileNumber) VALUES(S.inviteename, S.inviteephoneno)
> OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*;
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> $action | id | inviteename | InviteeMobileNumber
> :------ | -: | :---------- | :------------------
> INSERT  |  1 | aa          | 123<br>            
> INSERT  |  2 | bb          | 45
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM test
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | inviteename | InviteeMobileNumber
> -: | :---------- | :------------------
>  1 | aa          | 123<br>            
>  2 | bb          | 45
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=54e81db14e05dcfbff3cdf2a1d676656)*